# Sistema de Rating PHP

Tags: php

Boas eu estou criando um sistema simples de rating. 
O que pretendo é que a cada 2 ratings ele add uma Estrela, com o maximo de 5 estrelas.

Como faço isso?
Estive fazendo isto mas, nada de geito..

```
$star = "<li><a href='#'><i class='fa fa-star' aria-hidden='true'></i></a></li>";
$max_stars = 5;
$total_stars = $product_review / $max_stars * 1;

 for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++) {

  if($product_review >= $i) {

    if($total_stars) {

       echo $star; 
  }

  }
 }
```

E assim, eu criei isto mas... estou 100% confuso.. porque ele faz exatamente isso, soque add 1 estrela a cada 1 review...
Sera que fiz o codigo certo?

Answer (score 0):

add um campo no DB para armazenar a quantidade de votos, depois na hora de receber faz uma formatação (quantidade / 2), se a quantidade for = 5 bloqueia para nao votar mais, se nao, cria o formulário, link, sla, para poder votar e salvar no bd